# How to remove part of a string in php

Tags: php, string

I am getting this response from my server: 2015-07-31 09:35:58 MSK
(Please note that this changes whenever I submit my form).

I stumbled upon these codes:

```
$string= $arr2['paynet-processing-date']; //Where '$arr2['paynet-processing-date']' gives me the value '2015-07-31 09:35:58 MSK'
    $s = explode(" ",$string);
    unset($s[2]);
    $s = implode(" ",$s);
    print "$s\n";
```

I want to get only the date which is '2015-07-31'

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `datetime` value. Use `date` & `strtotime` together -

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr2['paynet-processing-date']));
```

**Output**

```
2015-07-31
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and it works when I echo it. However, the inserted data value is '2001'... 

Wild guess, since the date as of now is '2015-08-06' and 2015 subtracted to 8 subtracted to 6 = 2001 .... does the portion ''Y-m-d'' affects?

I used this code to insert:

         $transaction_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr2['paynet-processing-date']));

I hope you could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: *2015 subtracted to 8 subtracted to 6 = 2001* ??

Comment: Yes.. but that is only a wild guess why the server is inserting '2001' instead of ''2015-08-06'.. How can I be able to insert the correct value on my server? I am using this code:

      $transaction_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr2['paynet-processing-date']));

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: I used VARCHAR(120)as a data type for the column 'Transaction Date' where I inser the value of $Transaction_date. 

I also tried this code:
$string = $arr2['paynet-processing-date'];
    $parts = explode(" ", $string);
    $transaction_date = $parts[0];

but now I get 2000 since the date is '2015-8-7'.

Comment: Why are you using `explode` again?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already found `explode()` which might be used in this case:

```
<?php
    $string = "2015-07-31 09:35:58 MSK"
    $parts = explode(" ", $string);
    $date = $parts[0];

    var_dump($date);
```

A more elegant (and safe for different date formats) way of getting the desired result would be `date_parse` (PHP>5) or `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```
<?php
    $date = date_parse("2015-07-31 09:35:58 MSK");
    echo $date['year'] . '-' . $date['month'] . '-' . $date['day'];
```